# Internationalization support better in Velocity or FreeMarker?

Tags: jsp, internationalization, velocity, template-engine, freemarker

Internationalization is important for us.  So in choosing a template system for emails and other non-web (we use spring webmvc/JSP for web) templating needs, I need to know which handles translating phrases and formatting numbers, currency, dates, etc best.  I also read StringTemplate has a focus on internationalization and localization.  But I haven't heard much about StringTemplate.

Is Velocity or FreeMarker better?  I know FreeMarker boasts about its internationalization capabilities, but is Velocity really just as good?

Comment: hi, check this out: http://rythm.gelinsoft.com/doc/feature#i18n

Answer (score 1):

Freemarker has more i18n support built into the core engine.  However, Velocity with the addition of the VelocityTools project offers more i18n functionality, i believe.  Spring, too, provides some i18n support that can be used in Velocity.

Personally, my preference for i18n in templating is to use the VelocityTools support, but i'm biased because i wrote most of that.  In particular, i'm fond of the ResourceTool ($text) and the DateTool ($date) for their power and flexibility.

I've never looked into StringTemplate's i18n abilities, but they usually make very solid stuff, if a bit more restrictive than i prefer.  If they said they focus on i18n and whatnot, i'd believe them.

Comment: Does Velocity & Tools support the same messages_*.properties files Spring/JSP uses for translation phrases?  I'd certainly like to reuse that mechanism.

Comment: VelocityTools has a ResourceTool that uses resource bundles and {0} {1} arguments, which i believe is the same as Spring's system.  Both are java.util.ResourceBundle underneath, i believe.